# speed up code to generate list of animal names

Tags: vb.net

I have about 5 animal names in animals.txt when I run the code everything works and its fast.. when I put 800 animal names inside the text file each line by line it takes for ever.. more than 1 hour to finish.. how can I speed up this process ?

```
Private Sub GenerateList()
    Dim animalsList As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadLines("C:\animals.txt").ToList()

    Dim query = From firstWord In animalsList From secondWord In animalsList Where firstWord <> secondWord Select String.Format("{0}_{1}", firstWord, secondWord)

    Dim allKeys As String = ""
    For Each item In query
        allKeys += item & vbCrLf
        Label2.Text += 1
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next

    RichTextBox1.Text = allKeys
End Sub
```

Comment: It may help to have an index, e.g., use a database. You are currently looking at an n^2 operation. 5x5 is acceptable but 800x800 is a bigger number. Where is the animal list from?

Comment: Oh dear. AllKeys being a List<String> and then using String.Join, or a Allkeys being a StringBuilder would be better. And Application.DoEvents in general indicates a misstep in the design process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `allKeys` a StringBuilder. Then do `allKeys.AppendLine(item)` in the loop. Finally, set

```
RichTextBox1.Text = allKeys.ToString()
```

**EDIT:** Regarding excessive `DoEvents`, it could be an issue as well, but unlikely to cause as many slowdowns. To prove this point, I put this code in Form_Load event inside an empty WinForms app - runs in ~0.25sec:

```
Dim sw As New Stopwatch
sw.Start()
For i = 1 To 800000
  Application.DoEvents()
Next
sw.Stop()
MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString)
```

Putting the above into a Button click handler does not change the results, so these dummy calls are pretty fast, if nothing is actually happening.

Another point of interest is the LINQ query. I would rewrite it to use dictionaries or hashsets to be sure it's as fast as possible. However, before you do anything beside StringBuilder, use profiler, to see what's causing the slowdowns.

Comment: Good idea... how do you know this is where the slowdown occurs?

Comment: And he should absolutely get rid of the `Label2.Text += 1` which would not work for his cause anyways, as well as the `Application.DoEvents`. Updating a control and the DoEvents is probabaly whats killing his performace as well. But also absolutely use a StringBuilder like you said.

Comment: @Tofutim: The Stringbuilder is much faster than simple string concats. This is due to memory management internally.

Comment: I suspect the problem is really doing Application.DoEvents 800x800 times, rather than the string concatenation (or the comparison)

Comment: @tofutim: 99% of performance bottlenecks occur because people are NOT using StringBuilder. This was a wild guess. I once optimized my own (old) code to use a StringBuilder and it went from 10sec to 0.1sec. Using profiler is highly recommended to determine the actual cause.

Comment: Yep I had the exact same story. Exported 1.2M double values into a tab separated file and string builder cut the time from "go make yourself another coffee" to basically instant. Wether or not it's the biggest bottleneck in this example is hard to say but it's essential as well. No point in arguing given that it's also exactly as much work to implement than the normal concats ;-)

Comment: @Neolisk I removed the doEvents, Label and changed the allKeys into a StringBuilder. then ran the code and it took 3 seconds to finish 800x800 thanks

Comment: @Plutonix: [Repetition is the mother of all learning](http://blog.brainscape.com/2011/05/repetition-learning/).